# CiviMember Sync with Wordpress usernames

Tags: wordpress, civimember, webform-civicrm

1. How can I add a bulk operation to give certain individuals a membership on CiviCRM? for example, from a group
2. I want to sync those who are given memberships to give them a wordpress user accesss (already configured that).
   BUT when I sync them now, the username would the individual's prefix, first name, middle name, last name (ex. Mr-john-joe-smith), which is too long. **how can I make the format for the usernames?**
3. what would the default password be for the synced membership users afterwards?
4. CiviCRM syncs wordpress users to another individual that doesn't have to do anything with their name, email, phone number. How can I fix that before making the bulk operation.

Comment: So after testing, I figured that the issue is from the CiviCRM WordPress Profile Sync plugin. It is syncing the new wordpress user to the wrong civicrm individual. Is there a fix for the plugin or is there another plugin that can help with syncing the  users with the correct contact to CiviCRM.

Comment: Can you let me know how I can reproduce the behaviour of CiviCRM WordPress Profile Sync?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I add a bulk operation to give certain individuals a membership on CiviCRM? for example, from a group

I'll defer to someone with deeper knowledge of CiviCRM internals on this one. It's a separate question, really, which you may want to post as such.

> I want to sync those who are given memberships to give them a wordpress user access (already configured that). BUT when I sync them now, the username would the individual's prefix, first name, middle name, last name (ex. Mr-john-joe-smith), which is too long. how can I make the format for the usernames?

Please refer to [this thread on GitHub](https://github.com/christianwach/civicrm-wp-member-sync/issues/16) which provides a technique for you to define your own username format.

> what would the default password be for the synced membership users afterwards?

Newly-created WordPress users can set their own password by visiting the WordPress "Lost Password" screen.

> CiviCRM syncs wordpress users to another individual that doesn't have to do anything with their name, email, phone number. How can I fix that before making the bulk operation.

I think others have answered this elsewhere.